# How to SelectAll in a WinForms virtual ListView?

Tags: winforms, listview, virtual

What is the correct/managed way to `SelectAll` in a .NET listview *that is in virtual mode*?

When a ListView's `VirtualMode` is enabled, the notion of selecting a `ListViewItem` goes away. The only thing you select are *indexes*. These are accessible through the [`SelectedIndices`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.selectedindices.aspx) property.

### Workaround #1

The first hack is to add iteratively add every index to the `SelectedIncides` collection:

```
this.BeginUpdate();
try
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.VirtualListSize; i++)
        this.SelectedIndices.Add(i);
}
finally     
{
    this.EndUpdate();
}
```

In addition to being poorly designed (a busy loop counting to a hundred thousand), it's poorly performing ([it throws an `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event every iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86793/how-to-avoid-thousands-of-needless-listview-selectedindexchanged-events)). Given that the listview is in virtual mode, it is not unreasonable to expect that there will be quite a few items in the list.

### Workaround #2

The Windows `ListView` control is fully capable of selecting all items at once. Sending the listview a [`LVM_SETITEMSTATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) message, telling it so "select" all items.:

```
LVITEM lvi;
lvi.stateMask = 2; //only bit 2 (LVIS_SELECTED) is valid
lvi.state = 2;     //setting bit two on (i.e. selected)

SendMessage(listview.Handle, LVM_SETITEMSTATE, -1, lvi); //-1 = apply to all items
```

This works well enough. It happens instantly, and at most only two events are raised:

```
class NativeMethods
{
    private const int LVM_SETITEMSTATE = LVM_FIRST + 43;

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct LVITEM
    {
        public int mask;
        public int iItem;
        public int iSubItem;
        public int state;
        public int stateMask;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]public string pszText;
        public int cchTextMax;
        public int iImage;
        public IntPtr lParam;
        public int iIndent;
        public int iGroupId;
        public int cColumns;
        public IntPtr puColumns;
    };

    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SendMessage", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public static extern IntPtr SendMessageLVItem(HandleRef hWnd, int msg, int wParam, ref LVITEM lvi);

    /// <summary>
    /// Select all rows on the given listview
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="listView">The listview whose items are to be selected</param>
    public static void SelectAllItems(ListView listView)
    {
        NativeMethods.SetItemState(listView, -1, 2, 2);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Set the item state on the given item
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="list">The listview whose item's state is to be changed</param>
    /// <param name="itemIndex">The index of the item to be changed</param>
    /// <param name="mask">Which bits of the value are to be set?</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value to be set</param>
    public static void SetItemState(ListView listView, int itemIndex, int mask, int value)
    {
        LVITEM lvItem = new LVITEM();
        lvItem.stateMask = mask;
        lvItem.state = value;
        SendMessageLVItem(new HandleRef(listView, listView.Handle), LVM_SETITEMSTATE, itemIndex, ref lvItem);
    }
}
```

But it relies on P/Invoke interop. It also relies on the truth that the .NET `ListView` is a wrapper around the Windows `ListView` control. This is not always true.

So i'm hoping for the correct, managed, way to `SelectAll` is a .NET WinForms ListView.

### Bonus Chatter

There is no need to resort to P/Invoke in order to *deselect* all items in a listview:

```
LVITEM lvi;
lvi.stateMask = 2; //only bit 2 (LVIS_SELECTED) is valid
lvi.state = 1;     //setting bit two off (i.e. unselected)

SendMessage(listview.Handle, LVM_SETITEMSTATE, -1, lvi); //-1 = apply to all items
```

the managed equivalent is just as fast:

```
listView.SelectedIndices.Clear();
```

### Bonus Reading

- Ian Boyd wonders [how to `SelectAll` items of a ***non-virtual*** `ListView`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/87101/how-to-selectall-selectnone-in-net-2-0-listview)
- Making "select all" faster definitely helps [someone who wants to add Ctrl+A support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019388/adding-a-select-all-shortcut-ctrl-a-to-a-net-listview)

Comment: Another person who is afraid of P/Invoke? I just don't get it. The support for this is so extensive in the .NET Framework at least in part because they *knew* it wasn't a complete wrapper around the Win32 API and was never intended to be. When you start doing things that are outside of the typical 80% cases (and virtual mode list views definitely qualify), you'll need to drop to a lower level. You already know how to do it at the Win32 level, the WinForms control wraps the Win32 control, bingo bango problem solved.

Comment: @CodyGray Which is fine, except when the ListView is not backed by a Win32 ListView (e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf2k718k.aspx). i also want to be a *good* developer, and not be the ***cause*** of compatibility problems.

Comment: Are you targeting the compact framework? If not, then you know that it's going to be backed by a Win32 ListView. That much is a contract, guaranteed in the documentation as I read it. I very much sympathize with the desire to be a good developer and pay your taxes, but I don't think this is an instance of that. (I don't think this deserves a downvote though; it's still a reasonable question, even if I think you're vastly overthinking the problem.)

Comment: @CodyGray i would certainly agree that the WinForms `ListView` on Win32 is a lost cause. So many people P/Invoke to the undocumented internal control behind it that if Microsoft were to upgrade it to the WPF listview that a lot of existing code would break. But i certainly don't want to contribute to the world of poor developers who cause compatibility problems. The counter-argument is, "Well if Microsoft would have just provided the functionality we needed there would be no need to P/Invoke", which is quite true for Clearing, or setting the column sort glyph.

Comment: (Time passes.) How's the compatibility with WinForms on Linux? http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/winforms/

Comment: To put some numbers on things: individually selecting 554,253 lines takes about 24 seconds on my Win10 x64 system. Using P/Invoke to select all takes 4 milliseconds. The latter also causes a single VirtualItemsSelectionRangeChanged event, instead of one ItemSelectionChanged event per line. (I'm tracking the selection state separately because it takes 2.5 seconds to query the individual selection states with a foreach loop.)